# Some code redirect to https

Tags: redirect, https

For some reason my Magento shop always redirect to https.
I set config -> web -> unsecure -> base url to http://, so that can not be the problem.
Changed also store view to check all views.

And htaccess is also not redirecting to https.

But I do not know where in my code the site is redirecting to https.
I already changed to the default Magento theme, but still the website is redirecting to https.

Maybe I edit a core file a time ago, but I do not know what file it can be.

Is there a way to find the location of this problem?

Comment: Please check storewise configuarion.. goto system>Configuration> on the left panel chnage the scope

Comment: @AmitBera Checked this also, but still redirecting. In what core files can this be managed? Maybe I changed something there a time ago..!?

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is the core, `grep` for `https`.
2. If it is the database search for `https`.

Make sure your cache is up to date, so it is no old setting.

You can put a `die()` in the first line of your `index.php` to make sure it is not your apache/nginx

Comment: Thanks, but how can I search inside files on server by using FTP? Because I can only search for filenames and filedate etc. Not inside a file.

Comment: You can't afaik. You SSH. If you don't have SSH think about downloading everything and search then. And yes, what you learn from it: Have a hoster which allows SSH.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have installed extension that overwrites your frontend secure url, it sets all shop to https in config.xml

```
<secure_url>
          ...
        </secure_url>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: Can this only be defined in the folder app/code/ ? Or also inside the folder app/design/?

Comment: app/code/ look for new extensions